# Expo React Native NetInfo crashing

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-community-netinfo

#### Environment

```
  Expo CLI 3.11.7 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Linux 5.0 Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
      Shell: 4.4.20 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 12.14.0 - /usr/bin/node
      npm: 6.13.4 - /usr/bin/npm
    npmPackages:
      @types/react: ~16.9.0 => 16.9.17 
      @types/react-native: ~0.60.23 => 0.60.25 
      expo: ~36.0.0 => 36.0.2 
      react: ~16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
      react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz => 0.61.4 
      react-navigation: ^4.0.10 => 4.0.10 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      expo-cli: 3.11.7
```

#### Problem

I installed netInfo in expo using the recommended command by expo documentation here https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/netinfo/ : `expo install @react-native-community/netinfo`
After that I just tried to get the status of the connection to check if everything was working fine adding the next code:

```
import NetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo';

const MyCases = ({ cases }: Props) => {
useEffect(() => {
      (async function anyNameFunction() {
         const netInfoState = await NetInfo.fetch();
         console.warn(netInfoState);
      })();
   }, []);
};
```

After doing the mentioned previous steps any time I opened the app in iOS it crashes instantly and closes.
By the other hand, in android it doesn't closes but it shows this error message: `RNCNetInfo.getCurrentState got 3 arguments, expected 2`
I don't know what to do because, supposedly, in Expo enviroment linking is not needed and not possible

Answer (score 0):

This bug is related to netinfo version@4.x.x to fix that just update the module to version @5.0.0